# how to deal with replicate weights equal zero in R?

Tags: r, survey

I have zero values for some replicate and sampling weights. Therefore, when I use Svycoxph from the “survey” package, I get an error message that the “package Invalid weights, must be >0”. I think that one way might be to exclude these observations. I wonder if there is a way to keep those observations for the Cox proportional hazards model?

Thanks!
Julia

Comment: You will need to describe what sort of interpretation you would be putting on a case with zero weight.

Comment: a replicate weight of zero with a non-zero main weight might be a mistake in your microdata?  you might want to alert the survey administrator.

Comment: if you don't care, set the weights to some relatively tiny value like `0.0001`

Comment: Thanks! The replicate weights with zero values were assigned for observations with excluded PSUs (not quite sure why they were excluded as did not learn it in detail yet). The data are NHANES III. Julia

Comment: @user3036922 ahh, i bet that the zero weights are respondents who received the interview-only survey but not the mobile examination component.  if that's the case, then those zero weights *should* be removed from your data set prior to any sort of analyses.  read more about the difference here  http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/national%20health%20and%20nutrition%20examination%20survey%20%28nhanes%29

Answer (score 1):

Zero replicate weights are perfectly normal -- with jackknife replicates they will be observations from the PSU being left out; with bootstrap replicates they will be from PSUs that appeared zero times in a particular resample. Zero sampling weights, on the other hand, don't make a lot of sense and probably indicate observations that aren't in the sample or aren't in the sampling frame (personally, I'd code these as `NA`)

The `coxph()` function in the `survival` package can't handle negative or zero weights, and that's what `svycoxph()` calls.  For replicate weights,  `svycoxph()` adds a small value (1e-10) to weights to stop problems with zeros.

However, `svycoxph()` can't handle zero sampling weights. You probably want to remove these before constructing the design object.